# Tcl lappend returning unexpected results

Tags: list, tcl, embedded-linux, tclsh

I am going through the [Tcl tutorial](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl15.html) and the lappend operator is returning unexpected results.

I am running this on F5 load-balancing hardware's command line interface. Here is the relevant system info:

```
~ \#  cat /proc/version
  Linux version 2.6.32-431.56.1.el6.f5.x86_64 (f5cm@build19) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Jun 8 11:41:48 PDT 2016

% puts $tcl_version
8.5
```

I attempted every permutation of variable grouping I could think of, and I was still unable to get results that I expect. It appears as though there is a buffer that is holding on to all the results of the command: 'puts' command and using it in the 'lappend' command. Here is the lines I executed. The first few 'puts' are just to show that nothing has been initialized yet:

```
% puts $l1

can't read "l1": no such variable

% puts $l2

can't read "l2": no such variable

% puts $l3

can't read "l3": no such variable

% puts $l4

can't read "l4": no such variable

% puts $l5

can't read "l5": no such variable

% set l1 { {item 1} {item 2} {item 3} }

 {item 1} {item 2} {item 3}

% set l2 { {item 4} {item 5} {item 6} }

 {item 4} {item 5} {item 6}

% set l3 [concat $l1 $l2]

{item 1} {item 2} {item 3} {item 4} {item 5} {item 6}

#things working as expected here
% puts $l3

{item 1} {item 2} {item 3} {item 4} {item 5} {item 6}

#this is where things start to get squirrelly. I would expect this to return the result of $l1 concat with $l2 and the result stored in $l1
% lappend $l1 $l2

{ {item 4} {item 5} {item 6} }

#as you can see, it appears to return the second argument when that argument is a list. 
% lappend $l2 $l1

{ {item 1} {item 2} {item 3} }

# $l1 remains unchanged. at the very least, according to the documentation,
# I would expect that second item would be treated as a single entity
# when it is a list, and that the fourth item in '% lappend $l2 $l1' would be $l1
% puts $l1

 {item 1} {item 2} {item 3}

#neither $l2 nor $l1 are modified as the result of the 'lappend' command.
% puts $l2

 {item 4} {item 5} {item 6}

#more squirrelly-ness. when the arguments being passed are individual, it seems as though the last call to 'puts' is what 'lappend' uses for its first argument. this is confirmed on the last 3 commands below. **strong text**
% lappend $l1 "a" "b" "c"

{ {item 4} {item 5} {item 6} } a b c

% puts $l1

 {item 1} {item 2} {item 3}

% lappend "$l1" "$l2"

**{ {item 4} {item 5} {item 6} } a b c { {item 4} {item 5} {item 6} }**

% puts $l1

 {item 1} {item 2} {item 3}

% puts $l2

 {item 4} {item 5} {item 6}

% set l4 [lappend $l1 $l2]

 **{ {item 4} {item 5} {item 6} } a b c { {item 4} {item 5} {item 6} } { {item 4} 
{item 5} {item 6} }**

% puts $l4

 { {item 4} {item 5} {item 6} } a b c { {item 4} {item 5} {item 6} } { {item 4} 
{item 5} {item 6} }

# confirmed. 'lappend' is using last call to 'puts' as its argument for it's first argument. this can't be intended behavior right?
% puts $l1
 {item 1} {item 2} {item 3}
% set l5 [lappend $l2 "a" "b" "c"]
 { {item 1} {item 2} {item 3} } a b c
% puts $l2
 {item 4} {item 5} {item 6}
```

I can't imagine that this behavior is intended.

Here's how I would imagine this should work:

```
#should return something like [$list1, [$list2]] or something like concat $list1 $list2
% lappend $list1 $list2

#should return each item concatenated to the end of $list1
% lappend $list1 "a" "b" "c"
```

If the answer is that lappend does not modify the first argument in place, and I have to use a set command to save the results of the lappend command, that is fine; However, the lappend command does not appear to be behaving in a consistent manner.

Thanks in advance for any help/insight.

Comment: You are invoking undefined behavior here. When you ran `lappend $l1 $l2`, `lappend` is expecting a writable variable as its first argument but you are giving it a read-only variable. Had it been `lappend l1 $l2` (note the absence of `$` in `l1`), it will work as expected. The equivalent of `concat $l1 $l2` is `lappend '' $l1 $l2`.

Comment: awesome. thanks. that's a neat little trick with the empty string.

Comment: That's not an empty string.  That's a variable named `''` .   Tcl does not use single quotes to quote anything.

Comment: This is all because “ {item 1} {item 2} {item 3} ” (with the spaces) is a valid (but very unusual) variable name in Tcl.

Comment: according to the documentation, everything enclosed in curly-brackets is treated as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lappend $l1 $l2` appends the contents of l2 to the variable NAMED by the contents of l1.  You want `lappend l1 $l2`, in much the same way that you set variables via `set l1 whatever`, rather than `set $l1 whatever`.

Comment: Ahh. got it thanks. It's kinda like C-style pointers. I want the list itself, not the contents of the list?

Comment: @JoeGuichebarou Because you are _modifying_ it, you want the _variable_ holding the list, not the list _value_ that was in the variable.

Answer (score 2):

`lappend` takes a variable name as its first argument, not a list.
In the case:

```
   set l1 [list a b c]
   lappend $l1 x
   puts [set {a b c}]
   # returns: x
```

`x` is appended to the variable named `{a b c}`.

Instead, use the variable name as the first argument to lappend:

```
   set l1 [list a b c]
   set l2 [list d e f]
   lappend l1 {*}$l2
   # result: a b c d e f
```

The general rule to remember is that if a Tcl command modifies its argument, pass a variable name.  If the Tcl command does not modify its argument, pass the value (this rule doesn't work for arrays).

References: [lappend](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm)

Comment: And unfortunately, that tutorial does not make a proper distinction in its syntax specifications.  I think for the time being, you'll need to pull up the manual pages also so that you can see the proper syntax.  There are also other tutorials available.